# Inconsistency in Category extensions iOS 10+

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, objective-c-category

I have a very strange issue that I cannot seem to see the cause of.

I have a category extension on NSDictionary that has a method called title. The method works as follows:

```
- (NSString*)title {
    return self[@"title"];
}
```

What this allows me to do, is have a conveniece method on a NSDictionary to return a title.

Here is an example of use:

```
NSDictionary *config = [mConfigManager currentConfig];

if ([config title]) {

    return [config title];
}
return @"";
```

Now this is where things get strange. On iOS 10 the title method **sometimes** returns nil. In cases where this returns nil, a manual call to `config[@"title"]` returns the value. As a result I have adjusted my code as follows:

```
NSDictionary *config = [mConfigManager currentConfig];

if ([config title]) {

    return [config title];
}
else if(config[@"title"])
{
    return config[@"title"];
}
return @"";
```

With the above code, this always returns the title (if it exists). However it sometimes only works for the `else if` case and not the category version.

**So the question is:**

Why would the category not return a value when it is doing exactly the same thing as the manual call?

What makes this even stranger is that is does sometime work: See the following log output:

**first click**

```
(lldb) po [config title]
Joe Bloggs
```

**second click**

```
(lldb) po [config title]
nil
(lldb) po config[@"title"]
Joe Bloggs
```

**Note:** The above logs both ran during the same instance of the app, triggered by selecting a table view cell. So this eliminates any cases where a deallocation or re-allocation could occur.

One thing I have noticed however, is that the console will not output the contents of `config` and instead returns the following error:

```
<object returned empty description>
```

The variable view however fully shows the object and all variables. The object is defined as `NSDictionaryM` in the variable list.

Any help with this would be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rename your method with a prefix and see if you can reproduce this. Also, what's going on inside `[mConfigManager currentConfig]`?

Comment: The line does not break at the times when it returns `nil` so it gives the impression that it isn't being called.  `[mConfigManager currentConfig]` just returns a NSDictionary object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely something else in the system, possibly (probably) from Apple, has also created a `title` method on `NSDictionary` in a category. When there are two methods with the same name defined in categories, it is undefined which one will be executed. (I personally encountered this when Apple added `pop` to `NSMutableArray` in a private category, and my program went haywire in unpredictable ways.)

You must prefix your category methods (i.e. `mc_title` or whatever). Apple *should* prefix their private methods, but they don't, so you must.

(Of course, wanting to add this method to `NSDictionary` strongly suggests that you really should create a small data class instead of using a dictionary for this, but that's a completely separate issue.)

Comment: I will give this a try and see if this is the issue

Comment: In regards to the design of the objects, the code was originally written by someone else, I have been brought in for bug fixes. Personally I would have gone down the class route too :)